# How do I escape the `\0 character` or why is my method not working? (C++, GTest)

Tags: c++, string, escaping, googletest

I am writing a function to test going from URL to a query name format. For example, the URL "google.com" should turn into "\x6google\x3com\0". But if I want to test matching this I thought I just had to do something like this:

```
    // Test first that "google.com" becomes "\6google\3com\0"
    EXPECT_EQ(
        test_dns_querier->url_to_qname(url_test),
        "\x6google\x3""com\\0" // Escaped
    );
```

The first \x6 is to match against the hex character in the qname format. Same with \x3. Then after \x3 I needed to stop and start a new string since the 'c' in 'com' gets mistaken as a hex character. Then I use '\' in order to get a backslash and finally a '0', but **here is where it goes wrong** (see the ctest output below).

```
8: Expected equality of these values:
8:   test_dns_querier->url_to_qname(url_test)
8:     Which is: "\x6google\x3" "com\0"
8:   "\x6google\x3""com\\0"
8:     Which is: "\x6google\x3" "com\\0"
8: [  FAILED  ] dns_query_tests.DemonstrateQNameURLConverision (0 ms)
```

For some reason my double backslash does not work. And when I remove one it still escapes the '0' in '\0'.

Why does the typical '\' not work in this case?

Comment: `Then after \x3 I needed to stop and start a new string since the 'c' in 'com' gets mistaken as a hex character.` This wouldn't happen if you'd use two digits.

Comment: If I add any about of 0s I get this. It's escaping my \x3 to a character '<':
`
8: Expected equality of these values:
8:   test_dns_querier->url_to_qname(url_test)
8:     Which is: "\x6google\x3" "com\0"
8:   "\x6google\x03com\\0"
8:     Which is: "\x6google<om\\0
`

Comment: If the title is correct, you might want `"\x6google\x3""com\0"s`. See [std::literals::string_literals::operator""s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s)

Comment: That specific string didnt work but I'm looking into literals and operator""s

Comment: Note that in C, a hex escape uses as many hex digits as follow the `\x` (and I'm tolerably certain the same applies in C++).  Using `\x03com` would not alter things; the `c` is part of the hex escape.  See [§6.4.4.4 Character constants](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4).  The 'escape sequence' rule is used in [§6.4.5 String literals](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5) too.  You have to use string concatenation to avoid nasty surprises ([§5.1.1.2 Translation phases](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2) phases 5 & 6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To embed zero in a string literal, write `\0` or `\x00`. But in most contexts, char arrays (including string literals) are treated as C strings, i.e. zero-terminated. Thus the first embedded zero will be considered as string end and not its part. Indeed, that is the only way as the size is not passed along string (even string literal, although it has one).

So, you need:

1. Return your string from `url_to_qname` as something that supports embedded zeroes. `std::string` is okay.
2. Pass the string literal in a similar way. In C++17, you can use `std::string_view` for that: write your literal as `"\x06google\x03com\x00"sv` (after `using namespace std::literals` or likewise) and it will be converted to `std::string_view` in a way preserving embedded zeroes. Before C++17 that would need a bit of template or macro magic though, as things like `std::string("\x06google\x03com\x00")` don’t work (that constructor supports C strings only).

UPDATE: as @273K pointed out there is also `""s` which is available a bit earlier, since C++14.

Comment: `test_dns_querier->url_to_qname(url_test)` already returns `std::string`.